# Golang structure field's name and unmarshalling into this structure

Tags: json, go, structure, unmarshalling

I wrote an example program to illustrate my question, and it can be viewed here:
https://play.golang.org/p/6776lYcbBR

So my question is:

when a structure (***GameOne***) field's name starts with a capital letter, ***json.Unmarshal*** works as expected;
when it starts with a lower-case letter (***GameTwo***), the field value is set to its default.

Why is this so? Has it something to do with scope/visibility rules?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My structures are not marshalling into json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452004/my-structures-are-not-marshalling-into-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.Unmarshal` sets only the export fields in a struct and for exporting a field the first letter must be capital.
For more information I highly suggest you to take a look to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) (emphasis added):

> Unmarshal will only set **exported fields of the struct**.

Fields which begin with a lowercase letter are, of course, not exported. So there's no way for the JSON marshaler (or indeed anything at all outside of your package) to affect them.